# RSA Encryption using existing public key

Tags: ios, iphone, encryption, ios7, public-key-encryption

I am trying to encrypt NSData with the following method:

```
- (NSData *) encryptWithData:(NSData *)content {

size_t plainLen = [content length];

void *plain = malloc(plainLen);
[content getBytes:plain
           length:plainLen];

size_t cipherLen = 256;
void *cipher = malloc(cipherLen);

OSStatus returnCode = SecKeyEncrypt("PUBLIC KEY HERE", kSecPaddingPKCS1, plain,
                                    plainLen, cipher, &cipherLen);

NSData *result = nil;
if (returnCode != 0) {
    NSLog(@"SecKeyEncrypt fail. Error Code: %ld", returnCode);
}
else {
    result = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipher
                            length:cipherLen];
}

free(plain);
free(cipher);

return result;
```

}

Where it is written **"PUBLIC KEY HERE"** I want to load an existing public key I already copied to my bundle. How can I do that?

Comment: How did you copied to your bundle?

Comment: just dragged it into xcode...

Comment: Is that a string's file?

Comment: get the content of the file you dragged to bundle and use as key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example use a certificate file which contains a public key:

```
NSData *certificateData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:certificateURL options:0 error:&error];
if (certificateData) {
    SecCertificateRef certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef)(certificateData));
    // ...
    SecKeyRef publicKey;
    SecCertificateCopyPublicKey(certificate, &publicKey);
    // ...
}
```

To load data from the bundle:

```
NSArray *certificateURLs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLsForResourcesWithExtension:@"cer" subdirectory:@"myCertificates"];
for (NSURL *certificateURL in certificateURLs) {
    NSData *certificateData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:certificateURL options:0 error:&error];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I give that a go...and the public key must have *.pem extension?!

Comment: No, you use a certificate, which is in the `DER` format and has for example a `cer` extension. You can create new key pairs using the "Keychain Access" tool. For example create a self signed root certificate. It will contain a public and private key.

Comment: You can use a S/MIME certificate. This will allow you to sign, and encrypt data. At the end it doesn't matter much. The difference are just the flags which are set for the certificate verification. But when you use a certificate programatically, you can just ignore these flags.

Comment: Thx for your help..but if i create a s/mime cert, i am only able to export the Private Key as *.cer! The public key only as *.pem from the keychain...

Comment: 1. Right click on the new certificate. 2. Select "export" 3. Change the export format to ".cer"

Comment: I am not able to change it...the only format i can pick is *.pem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49122/discussion-between-chrizstone-and-flovdis)

Comment: I don´t know why but this function SecCertificateCopyPublicKey always returns nil for the public key...